# How to Hidden column in winform list box?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am doing Student Attendance project for college in win form with MySQL(C#).

see the below picture,. this is my form. In that i add three listbox with single column.(student no.)

In that My Client want Student name only and student no they do not want to display.

but i want to save the record based on the Student no. So is it possible Hidden Column in Listbox?.

My Code is

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                MySqlDataReader Reader;
                command.CommandText = "select admin_no from student_admision_master where course='" + course_code + "' AND year='" + year_code + "' AND sem='" + semester_code + "' AND batch='" + batch_code + "'";
                connection.Open();
                Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
                }
                connection.Close();
```

student_admision_master datatable have all the detail of student. name, father name, address etc...

Please Give an idea to do this!....

[image]

Comment: Your fault is, that you only get the student number from your database. Extend your select query to fetch the student name and then create a class, which represents one item of your result (student number, student name). After that you can add the item to your ListBox and set the DisplayMember to "StudentName". This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you add the items to your ListBoxes? Please show some us some code.

You have a property called **DisplayMember** on your ListBox. Try to set your student name property as DisplayMember on your ListBox.

Answer (score 2):

Add the entire Student object to each listbox. Then either set the `DisplayMember` property to the property of the student object that contains the string you want to display, or simply override the `ToString` method of the `Student` class to give an appropriate string for displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class like this ***pseudocode***:

```
public class Student {
   public string Property1{get;set;}
   public string Property2{get;set;}
}
```

Add to your listbox a colleciton of `Student` objects and assign **DisplayMember**,as suggests
@Mariusz to the property name you want to display, cause it's not very clear from post what you want to hide and what you want to show.

Regards.

Comment: ok :) I didn't understand that "Student No" is a  field name actually.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the column width property to zero.
Cheers.